# Sticky navbar working on jsfiddle, but not as expected on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, localhost, navbar, sticky

I've put together a [**sticky navbar**](https://jsfiddle.net/qz7531bu/68/) that appears after 10px in a relative position, and then becomes fixed once it scrolls past `offset().top`.
This works as desired on the fiddle, but on localhost (with the exact same code) the navbar is fixed as soon as it appears (it ought to be relatively positioned till the offset point, as demonstrated in the fiddle).

Would appreciate any insight on why it's behaving different on the localhost?

*Also, I've added jquery (`<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`) and **there are no console errors**.*

Here is the javascript as i'm running it from the localhost:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('navig').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  var fixed = false;
  var topTrigger = $('#navig').offset().top;

  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
      document.getElementById('arr_downpoint').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById('navig').style.visibility = 'visible';   
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('arr_downpoint').style.visibility = 'visible';
      document.getElementById('navig').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }    

  });
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() >= topTrigger ) {
      if( !fixed ) {
        fixed = true;
        $('#navig').css({'position':'fixed', 'top':'0'});
      }
    } else {
      if( fixed ) {
        fixed = false;
        $('#navig').css({'position':'relative'});
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by it is not working? Did you check your console for the errors?

Comment: In jsFiddle, js code is wrapped in window onload handler. Set your snippet inside it too. That's said, even in jsFiddle, the code is really buggy...

Comment: You have a position absolute on  the HTML element nav in your css which may be a conflict, put it on a class .navclass or id instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping everything inside your `<script>` tag into `$(document).ready()` function:

```
$(function () {
  document.getElementById('navig').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  var fixed = false;
  var topTrigger = $('#navig').offset().top;

  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
      document.getElementById('arr_downpoint').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById('navig').style.visibility = 'visible';   
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('arr_downpoint').style.visibility = 'visible';
      document.getElementById('navig').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }   

  });
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() >= topTrigger ) {
      if( !fixed ) {
        fixed = true;
        $('#navig').css({'position':'fixed', 'top':'0'});
      }
    } else {
      if( fixed ) {
        fixed = false;
        $('#navig').css({'position':'relative'});
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: No part of the script works with that, it just displays as a static page , same on localhost   https://jsfiddle.net/qz7531bu/69/

Comment: Ok, sorry about that - the problem both in the fiddle and the localhost is that the the navbar needs to appear relative (at the bottom of header) till it hits offset when it becomes fixed.

Comment: @AgniScribe I don't understand?

Comment: I mean, the position of the navbar (as specified in css) is `position: absolute` at the bottom of the header. So when it touches 10px and appears and till it touches offset(). top, it needs to stay at the bottom of the header.